# Getting user email from Google Plus authentication, without GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, single-sign-on, google-plus

Is it possible to retrieve the user's email address after the user authenticate with their G+ account (Using G+ Android SDK)?
I know you can do that if you ask for GET_ACCOUNTS permission, but then I wouldn't need the G+ login...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is the email address (and not actually do anything with the account), you can use [AccountPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html) to allow the user to select a Google account.

Note that if there is only one Google account on the device, you get an immediate response back with no intervening dialog.

Comment: Thanks! Going to try that. Does it has anything to do with the G+ SDK?

Comment: @RonenYacobi - the only relation is that they are both part of Google Play Services, so you'd still have to follow the same [Google Play Services Setup steps](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: Note that I think that this API not requiring `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission is a bug and will be patched at some point. If want to get the user's account information such as their email address, I would still add the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission just to be on the safe side and to be open and honest with users on what your app is doing.

Comment: AccountPicker provides a good balance. The user, not your app, sees a lits of accounts, and the user decides whether to pick one for your app to work with. Feels like a low-privilege operation to me.

Comment: @TimBray - unless, of course, there is only one account, then the user gets no interaction at all yet the app has the user's email address (or account name from any other service) allowing the app to get information that perhaps the user would not have normally given the app had they seen a dialog or seen the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission on install. I've opened up discussion on this over on [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108723596340082219264/posts/TG4qJC1twCz)

Comment: Note that as of the latest version of Google Play Services, if you only have one account and do not include the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, then logcat gives the following warning: `The calling package does not have the android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS permission. Will display Chooser.` and the Chooser is displayed. If you do have the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, then the Chooser is not shown if there is only one account to choose from.